# Facing issue in Flutter Gradle file

Tags: android, flutter

Can any one have any idea why this error happening.

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G900H in debug mode...

Initializing gradle...

Resolving dependencies...

- Error running Gradle:
  Exit code 1 from: D:\NewFlutter\App\testapp\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: Please check GitHub issues for similar error messages. There might be suggestions how to fix.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yaa i tried but am not getting any proper solution...?

Comment: New versions of many plugins were released last week. Ensure you have the latest version.

Comment: let me check once..